# How to create Auxiliary (Higher Order Component) in preact?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am trying to build an application using preact and I have created a simple component known as LayoutComponent.

In Layout component I have used Auxilary component as shown below:

```
import { h } from 'preact';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
const Layout = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <div>
        Toolbar, Sidebar, Backdrop
        </div>
        <div>
            { props.children }
        </div>
    </Aux>
);
export default Layout;
```

And below mentioned is my Auxilary component code:

```
const Aux = ( props ) => props.children;
export default Aux;
```

When I am invoking LayoutComponent from my App.js render() method, the JSX content inside  tag is not getting displayed.

If I replace the  tag with  tag then it is working fine, but I don't need that extra div in my DOM structure.

The DOM is shown something like this in chrome if I use Aux tag.
[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a component must return exactly one direct child. In React, this was solved recently by introducing [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), but this feature is currently [not supported](https://github.com/developit/preact/issues/946) in Preact yet.
If you are sure that the component will only have one child, you could insert it like this:

```js
const Aux = (props) =>
  props.children.length === 1 && props.children[0];
```

However, since you want to insert two children in your example, the only way is indeed to wrap them in a `div` or any other tag like so:

```js
const Aux = (props) => (
  <div>
    { props.children }
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const aux = (props) => props.children;
export default aux;
```

just two line! :D